# redis unable to write to AOF due to disk space (AOF rewrite enabled)

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

redis version: 4.0.14

OS: FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p10 amd64

In the redis documentation around AOF it says after version 2.6 it should automatically trigger BGREWRITEAOF:

> Redis is able to automatically rewrite the AOF in background when it gets too big. The rewrite is completely safe as while Redis continues appending to the old file, a completely new one is produced with the minimal set of operations needed to create the current data set, and once this second file is ready Redis switches the two and starts appending to the new one.

It doesn't seem to be doing this. logs:

```
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 # MASTER timeout: no data nor PING received...
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 # Connection with master lost.
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 * Caching the disconnected master state.
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 * Connecting to MASTER 192.168.0.100:6412
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:19.992 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:21.596 # Error reply to PING from master: '-MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: No space left on device'
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:22.021 * Connecting to MASTER 192.168.0.100:6412
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:22.021 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:22.021 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:23.238 # Error reply to PING from master: '-MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: No space left on device'
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:24.050 * Connecting to MASTER 192.168.0.100:6412
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:24.050 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:24.050 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
774:S 04 Mar 17:21:25.682 # Error reply to PING from master: '-MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: No space left on device'
```

`$ info`

```
# Server
redis_version:4.0.14
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:b8839b63a68a4b99
redis_mode:cluster
os:FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p10 amd64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:kqueue
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:4.2.1
process_id:766
run_id:bf9d05b240cd776e4547729d062dd6f5a5e0f60d
tcp_port:6412
uptime_in_seconds:40930179
uptime_in_days:473
hz:10
lru_clock:4266405
executable:/usr/local/bin/redis-server
config_file:/usr/local/etc/redis_cluster/6412/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:115
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:11588787188
used_memory_human:10.79G
used_memory_rss:11588984900
used_memory_rss_human:10.79G
used_memory_peak:16230019258
used_memory_peak_human:15.12G
used_memory_peak_perc:71.40%
used_memory_overhead:301057836
used_memory_startup:1928680
used_memory_dataset:11287729352
used_memory_dataset_perc:97.42%
total_system_memory:0
total_system_memory_human:0B
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:27106127360
maxmemory_human:25.24G
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00
mem_allocator:libc
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:11838701
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1614662573
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:87
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:196
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:err
aof_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:6817578976
aof_base_size:5413636704
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:630994
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:56

# Stats
total_connections_received:456772
total_commands_processed:4953546081
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:205
total_net_input_bytes:685638114456
total_net_output_bytes:260383113923
instantaneous_input_kbps:51.50
instantaneous_output_kbps:31.54
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:62
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:23
expired_keys:176647087
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:863832269
keyspace_misses:891573350
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:1641619
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:90da82c2d4a4ff31b64721286b17b8716170be6c
master_replid2:a40e37f9dca7fab0b151a632564d4e5bd3163321
master_repl_offset:310200952366
second_repl_offset:308626210072
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:310199903791
repl_backlog_histlen:1048576

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:334704.88
used_cpu_user:192502.30
used_cpu_sys_children:1007.51
used_cpu_user_children:12385.73

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:1

# Keyspace
db0:keys=5665785,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
(0.50s)
```

When I try to run `BGREWRITEAOF` I get the following message:
`/: write failed, filesystem is full`

Please let me know if I need to put any more information here.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ran into the same issue , was there any fix identified for the same